# R plot: adding a title to the y-axis

Tags: r, plot

I would like to add a title for the y-axis of the top plot.
Of course, in the toy example below, I can use the ylab argument.
But I am looking for another option to fit with my actual problem.
It appears that mtext() does not do the job in this case.
Any other idea?

```
x11()
par(mfrow=c(2, 1))
plot(1:10, ylab = " ")
mtext(text = "y-label", side = 2, line = -2, outer = TRUE)
plot(1:10, ylab = " ")
```

[image]

Comment: What is the exact problem that you cannot use the `ylab` argument then?

Comment: @TJGorrie: I don't think it is necessary to deep into the details. But the idea is that I have a single function that builds the axes and then I use it to make different plots. Each plot has its own title for the y-axis.

Comment: @Hav0k: Thank you, but it seems to me it is not exactly that...

Comment: I think I know now what your actual problem is (the question wasn't really clear to me). Just get rid of the `outer` argument in `mtext`.

Comment: Thank you @Hav0k! If you make it an answer, then I will accept it ;-)

Comment: You're welcome. Just accept TJGorrie's answer, although the you can ignore the stuff regarding the `at` argument, IMO.

Answer (score 0):

`mtext(text = "y-label", side = 2,line=2, at=26, outer = FALSE)`

You will have to play around where `at=` is to find the sweet spot for both graphs but this will do what you are asking. 6 seems to be a good number for the bottom graph if anything. (Using the example)

If you imagine `line` to be an x co-ordinate and `at` to be a y co-ordinate then you can just play around until you find what fits.

Probably not as clean and cut as you wanted but it will work.